# Paste a text with Autohotkey containing special characters

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, script, autohotkey, paste

I'm using Word for making index cards for my studies and often I need to use the Equation feature. There's no hotkey for the subscripts and always opening the menu and chosing the desired one is pretty annoying. I found out the text representing the formulars on word and I just have to paste them to get the desired effect.

Example for X_y:

```
<mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"><mml:msub><mml:mrow><mml:mi>X</mml:mi></mml:mrow><mml:mrow><mml:mi>y</mml:mi></mml:mrow></mml:msub></mml:math>
```

I've already tried the send feature on Autohotkey but this text has to be pasted via the Paste-Feature, so I tried this:

```
 {
   temp := clipboardall
   clipboard := " <mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"><mml:msub><mml:mrow></mml:mrow><mml:mrow></mml:mrow></mml:msub></mml:math> "
   sendinput, ^v
   clipboard := temp
 }
return
```

However, now I'm getting an error:

```
Error at line 4,

The following variable name contains an illegal character:
"MathML""

The program will exit.
```

Obviously there's a problem with the quatation marks but how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Variable names **in an [expression](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expressions)** are not enclosed in percent signs  and
>
> **literal text must be quoted** to distinguish it from variables.
>
> **To include an quote-character inside a literal string, specify two consecutive quotes:**

```
clipboard := " <mml:math xmlns:mml=""http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"" xmlns:m=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math""><mml:msub><mml:mrow></mml:mrow><mml:mrow></mml:mrow></mml:msub></mml:math> "
```

Comment: Thank you! That does the trick